# Anonymous ScrollView listener in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

Consider next situation:

I have Fragment1 and this code inside onViewCreated:

```
scrollView.setScrollViewListener(new ScrollViewListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int top, int oldx, int oldy) {
  Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dr1);
}
)
```

Consider situation that I add some views into `scrollView` container after any background operations. Question is: is there any situation that i change my Fragment1 (pass `FragmentTransaction`) and add some views into `scrollView` container that leads to onScrollChanged invocation, and this invocation fire then my Fragment1 already was not added to `activity` that leads to `IllegalStateException` (because I call getResources())?

Is there any point to manually call setScrollListener(null) in onDestroyView method to prevent `IllegalStateException`?

Actually I face this error:

```
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment Fragment1{81de789} not attached to Activity
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:620)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.kinopoisk.ui.fragment.MovieFragment$9.onScrollChanged(MovieFragment.java:456)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at ru.kinopoisk.ui.views.ObservableScrollView.onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView.java:48)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ScrollView.onOverScrolled(ScrollView.java:811)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.overScrollBy(View.java:19859)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.ScrollView.computeScroll(ScrollView.java:1316)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15161)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3423)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1089)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15169)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15948)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3609)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3399)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:16181)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2690)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:15174)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:281)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:287)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:322)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2615)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2434)
10-08 15:29:32.174 2227-2227/? E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2067)
```

Comment: `Drawable drawable= getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dr1);`

Comment: @M D look at `getResources` `Fragment` realization first